# How to convert a UTC timestamp to hour, minute to display on the graph in Java?

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a graph that showed the index about managing fuel by time, with fuel's index on the vertical axis and time on the horizontal axis. I expect to show the type of time which got from timestamp to hour and minute. So what should I do exactly? I have this code:

```
strscr += "chartData.push({fuelLevel: "+arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel()+",timestamp: "+arrValue.get(i).getTimeStamp()+", detail:\""+detail+"\"});\n";
```

how to convert `arrValue.get(i).getTimeStamp()` to hour and minute?

Comment: You're not really showing us enough of this to properly help, but assuming the timestamp is something like "seconds since the epoch" consider using java.util.Calendar:   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Or if you are willing to add a dependency on apache commons lang, use DateUtils:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html

But in this case, apache's lib probably won't add a lot of value if this is all you use it for.

Here is an example of formatting the date:

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String result = sdf.format(d);
```

BTW, if your instance is a calendar, just use the getTime() method to get a date instance.

Comment: you're welcome, can you please click the check mark next to my answer?